# Вызов метода из импортированного jar файла. Ошибка .NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/service/ServiceRegistry

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

Здравствуйте. У меня одно приложение вызывает метод другого приложения(jar сборка Maven). Второе приложение добавлено в class path первого. Вызываемый метод должен делать запрос к базе данных mysql hibernate. Я закомментировал весь код этого метода и для теста просто прописал одну строку вывода в консоль System.out.println("Метод вызван"); Но получаю исключение
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В classpath нет Hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно было импортировать все баночки Hibernate и MySql. Да еще чтобы версии соответствовали. Было бы проще если бы вызывающее приложение было как и вызываемое собрано в Maven. Тогда просто те же зависимости бы добавил.